# Sql Server Storing SHA256 String as Question Marks

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, encryption, sha

I have followed this article on how to implement **password hashing and salting**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/608860/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-and-Impleme

I have implemented all the code mentioned in the article into my **MVC 5 web application**, however, whenever I **store the PasswordHash and Salt**, both of these strings save in my User table as **question marks, e.g, ????????????????**

The database I'm using is **Sql Server 2008 R2**. The two fields within my database User table have both got a **datatype of Nvarchar(100)**

I should also mention the data is being persisted to the database using **Entity Framework 5**.

Has anyone seen this before? I'm thinking it might be a datatype problem, i.e., shouldn't be Nvarchar, however, I don't really know.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use SHA-256 as password hash, it sucks since it's too fast. At minimum use PBKDF2 with at least 10000 iterations. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) on security.SE for a description of how secure password hashing actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem in `Utility.cs`:

```
    public static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
        return new string(chars);
    }
```

The function is fed random bytes. This is not how you create a random string. Characters are not meant to store binary data. Such strings will be hard to swallow for many components.

Use `Convert.ToBase64String` and don't trust random articles on the web. Validate what you find with your own understanding before using it.

Answer (score 1):

SHA256 are not string, are byte arrays. Use byte[] in your client code, use `VARBINARY` on the server code.